# Powershell cannot find file when run from dockerfile, but works when manually executed inside container

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell, docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I am trying to set up SSL for a ASP.NET web application that is running in a docker for windows container.  I am running on Windows 10.

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:23:10 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.8
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       afacb8b
  Built:            Wed Mar 11 01:37:20 2020
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     true
```

Below is my dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-1803
USER ContainerAdministrator

EXPOSE 443


ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .

RUN Add-WindowsFeature Web-Scripting-Tools

RUN Remove-WebSite -Name 'Default Web Site'

RUN New-Website -Name 'myApp' -IPAddress '*' -Port 443 -PhysicalPath C:\inetpub\wwwroot -ApplicationPool '.NET v4.5' -Ssl -SslFlags 0

#CMD ["powershell.exe", "-File", "AddCertificate.ps1"]

#RUN ["powershell", "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AddCertificate.ps1"]

RUN powershell.exe -Command "\
   Import-Module IISAdministration; \
   Import-Module WebAdministration; \
  $pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'passw0rd!' -Force -AsPlainText; \

  # Import the certificate and store it in a variable to bind to later; \
 $cert = Import-PfxCertificate -Exportable -FilePath C:\inetpub\wwwroot\selfCert.pfx -CertStoreLocation cert:\localMachine\My -Password $pwd; \
  # Take the imported certificate and bind it to all traffic toward port 443 (you need to specify IP if you want multiple apps on 1 docker which I believe is ill-advised); \
  New-Item -Path IIS:\SslBindings\0.0.0.0!443 -value $cert;"
```

Problem:  Docker fails with the error that selfCert.pfx is not found.

I tried moving all these commands to a powershell script and tried running that too.  Somehow docker/powershell cannot find my .ps1 file too.

When I connect to the container manually, I can see the files in the expected location.  I can also execute .PS1 successfully.  The problem occurs only when its executed from the dockerfile.

I tried USER ContainerAdministrator, also different ways of calling PowerShell with -Bypass -File but unable to run it from dockerfile.

Need some help in getting this run and identify why this is happening.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. As per my investigation, there is one **.dockerignore** file within the same directory which is causing these file path related restriction. We would require to mention these relative path ignore syntax in the **.dockerignore** file.

I have used Publish solution feature in visual studio then copied the content from Publish folder to the container working directory through docker file.

**Below steps have been followed:**

1. In Visual Studio, Publish the application solution in Publish folder: **/bin/Release/Publish**.
2. In dockerfile, use COPY command to copy the items from Publish folder( /bin/Release/Publish/ )[ instead of docker folder ] to container working directory .[**Command: COPY /bin/Release/Publish/ .**]
3. Include the above relative path ignore syntax in .dockerignore file like **!bin\Release\Publish*.**
4. Specify the .pfx file path in the SSL import powershell command in the docker file.
   [Command: **-FilePath C:\inetpub\wwwroot\selfCert.pfx** OR **-FilePath ./selfCert.pfx**]